# What should I write in "Working Relationship" field in job application

Tags: management, job-search, applications, employer-relations, references

I am applying for job online and the form includes an area for me to list my references and our "Working Relationship".

What should I write in that area?

Also, when I report to a person who is the only other person in the company, what is their position: owner/manager/MD/CEO?

Comment: working relationship is generally one of `managed by [this person]`, `colleague` or `managed [this person]`

Comment: @TZHX With a little more text, that would be a perfectly fine answer...

Answer (score 20):

One of:

- My Manager
- Directly Reported to me
- Indirectly Reported to me
- Colleague on the same team
- Colleague on another team
- Friend
- Mentor
- Family (best avoided when possible.)

Terms may vary about between culture / country

Comment: You may want to shorten them and nounify them. `Directly Reported to Me` ⇒ `Direct Report` (though I would avoid `underling`).

Comment: I prefer Michael Durrant's phrasing.  "Direct Report" is ambiguous.  Are you saying you are the direct report, or that they are?

Answer (score 6):

> What should I write in that area?

For the references you are putting down, how would you categorize the relationship: Is this person your manager, team lead, teammate, subordinate, or something else?  Where in the organizational chart are you in relation to the reference.  Was this person a client of yours?  Did you use this person as a vendor for some service?  There are more than a few possible answers here.

> Also, when I report to a person who is the only other person in the
>   company, what is their position: owner/manager/MD/CEO?

This can vary.  President, CEO, Owner, Founder, Creator, and Chairman are possibilities though it depends a bit on how the person views the company.  They may just see themselves as a Principal or Director and thus it is worth either asking or looking at their business card or an on-line profile like LinkedIn that may have their title.